# Extracting values from a list of dictionary in dataframe column and and create new column with

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe column named 'urls' containing a list of dictionary in each row. I want to get a value of specific key in a dictionary and make new column having that value for each row. For example, the row-index 0 of the 'url' column

```
df['urls'][0]
```

prints as below.

```
[{"start": 92, "end": 115, "expanded_url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bevk4X-FQsI/", "display_url": "instagram.com/p/Bevk4X-FQsI/"}]
```

I want to make a new column named 'expanded' and the row-index 0 should have

```
df['expanded'][0]
"https://www.instagram.com/p/Bevk4X-FQsI/"
```

So far I have tried

```
df['expanded'] = df['urls'].str[0].str.get('expanded_url')
```

this prints

```
df['expanded'][0]
NaN
```

and

```
df['urls'].str[0]
```

prints

```
[
```

I think something is wrong but do not understand where I am wrong.

Could anyone help here to fix it?

Comment: This means you have a string representation of a python object, not the object. Use `ast.literal_eval` or parse as json.

Comment: Thank you @mozway . it works after I use ast.literal_eval on the url column.

Comment: @mozway as the comment solved OP's problem, please consider sharing an answer with it.

Comment: @Gonçalo OP's question is unfortunately missing a reproducible example